# C#: HtmlAgilityPack extract inner text

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I am using HtmlAgilityPack. Is there a one line code that I can get all inner text of html, e.g., remove all html tags and scripts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.DocumentNode.InnerText
```

Note that this will return the text content of `<script>` tags.

To fix that, you can remove all of the `<script>` tags, like this:

```
foreach(var script in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
    script.Remove();
foreach(var style in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("style").ToArray())
    style.Remove();
```

Comment: It seems that DocumentNode does not have a function named Descendant?
"'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'Descendants'"

Comment: HTML Agility Pack V1.3.0.0, is it too old?

Comment: I used this code for solving a problem of mine. I do have one question though. How can removal be performed in a foreach loop ?

Comment: @WinCoder: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean isn't the collection on which foreach loop is being used can't be modified.

Comment: @WinCoder: That's why I call `ToArray()` to iterate on a separate copy.

Comment: Ok if you are iterating on a separate copy then how come the original is being modified.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple method. It may help you. This method can extract all specific tag's node. Then you can use the `HtmlNodeCollection[i].InnerText` to get its text.

```
    HtmlDocument hDoc;
    HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection;

    public void InitInstance(string htmlCode) {
        hDoc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
        nodeCollection = new HtmlNodeCollection();
    }
    private void GetAllNodesInnerTextByTagName(HtmlNode node, string tagName) {
        if (null == node.ChildNodes) {
            return ;
        } else {
            HtmlNodeCollection nCollection = node.SelectNodes( tagName );
            if( null != nCollection ) {
                for( int i=0; i<nCollection.Count; i++) {
                    nodeCollection.Add( nCollection[i]);
                    nCollection[i].Remove();
                }
            }
            nCollection=node.ChildNodes;
            if(null != nCollection) {
                for(int i=0;i<nCollection.Count; i++) {
                    GetAllNodesInnerTextByTagName( nCollection[i] , tagName );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: usually, an article's content always in <p> tags.