# BeautifulSoup and ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping, ironpython, beautifulsoup

Has anyone integrated BeautifulSoup with ASP.NET/C# (possibly using IronPython or otherwise)?
Is there a BeautifulSoup alternative or a port that works nicely with ASP.NET/C#

The intent of planning to use the library is to extract ***readable*** text from any random URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) is a similar project, but for C# and .NET

---

EDIT:

To extract all readable text:

```
document.DocumentNode.InnerText
```

Note that this will return the text content of `<script>` tags.

To fix that, you can remove all of the `<script>` tags, like this:

```
foreach(var script in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
    script.Remove();
foreach(var style in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("style").ToArray())
    style.Remove();
```

(Credit: [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text/2785108#2785108))

Comment: How would I use HAP for scraping readable text from a HTML page. In BeautifulSoup, it's very easy to do this.

Comment: Does the DocumentNode.InnerText get all the text within the <body> tags. My worry is that I need to support this for URLs that do not follow any standard. There might be gunk all over. Is HAP smart enough to distinguish between readable text and irrelevant HTML tags, comments, client scripts

Comment: HAP is pretty smart at detecting what text will be output by a browser, but of course many sites these days will make a lot of changes to the text visible in the final render with css, javascript and images.  So really the only true way to determine what is a person could read when the page is rendered by a browser, would be to render it in a browser...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite old, but I decided to post this for future reference.
I came across this searching for a similar solution.

I found a library built on top of Html Agility Pack called scrapysharp

I've used it in quite similar manner as I would BeautifulSoup
https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/wiki/Home (EDIT: broken link, project moved to https://github.com/rflechner/ScrapySharp)

EDIT: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ScrapySharp/ has the package

Answer (score 2):

You could try this although it currently has a few bugs:

> http://nsoup.codeplex.com/