# Strip HTML, Keep Bold/Strong Tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have a small bit of regex that strips out all HTML, and works great. What I need to do now, is strip out all HTML, but KEEP the `<b>` and `<strong>` tags in tact.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
shortDesc = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(shortDesc, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep using regex, you may as well fudge it by replacing `<b>` with `{b}` before, then back again after your regex.

Comment: @George - I'm not really seeing how that will help. He's going to have to recognize the tags he wants to keep and throw out everything else, so he may as well do both in one <strike>regex</strike> **DOM parsing operation.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Stop trying to [parse HTML with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
2. Use something like [HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357170/beautifulsoup-and-asp-net-c)

Comment: This is something we do once, on one template, in a huge site. I don't really want to add a project dependency for a one time usage thing, if I don't have to.

Comment: It's also only being used on a short description, typically two sentences. This isn't being used to screen scrape a large amount of data.

Comment: Parsing HTML is hard. It doesn't matter if you don't want to do it often or on large amounts of data, you still need a robust parser in order to cope with it safely.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple extension of your regex that should work pretty well:

```cs
Regex re = new Regex(@"<(?!/?(?:strong|b)\b)[^>]*>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
text = re.Replace(text, "");
```

Comment: I just want to emphasize that although this will work for most cases, the other posters are still correct that it is not a full solution, and there is lots of valid HTML that will break it. @Ridge I know you already know this, but I want to make sure OP does too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered in your comments, a careful usage of regular expressions (though usually shunned for obvious reasons) could be employed, provided that you meet the following requirement:

1. The HTML is not malformed.
2. It won't contain "<" and ">" as part of **anything other than opening / closing tags **.

If the html page is under your control, it is fairly reasonable to assume that you could meet both conditions, otherwise I wouldn't bother.

In your case, you can use the overloaded instance of the **Replace** method that accepts a **MatchEvaluator** delegate along with its other parameters.

Usage example:

```
MatchEvaluator replaceCallback = new MatchEvaluator(MatchHandler);
Regex RE = new Regex(matchPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string newString = RE.Replace(source, replaceCallback);
```

MatchHandler example:

```
public static string MatchHandler(Match theMatch) {
  if (theMatch.Value.StartsWith("<b>") || ...) {
    return theMatch.Value;  //return as is
  }
  //else return empty string
  return "";
}
```