# How to get plaintext from the response of a WebRequest class in C#

Tags: c#, html, httpwebrequest, webrequest, plaintext

I want to get plain text using WebRequest class, just like what we get when we use `webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText` . I have tried the following code

```
public string request_Resource()
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myurl);
   Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
   WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
   wb.DocumentText = sr.ReadToEnd();
   return wb.Document.Body.InnerText;
}
```

when i execute this is get a `NullReferenceException`.

Is there a better way to get a plain text.

Note: I cannot use webbrowser control directly to load the webpage, because, i don't want to deal with all those events that fire up multiple times when ever a page is loaded.

**UPDATE: I have changed my code to use WebClient Class instead of WebRequest upon suggestion
My code looks something like this now**

```
public string request_Resource()
{
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.Proxy = null;
   //The user agent header is added to avoid any possible errors
   wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C)");
   return wc.DownloadString(myurl);
}
```

**I am considering using HTML Utility Pack, can anyone suggest any better alternative.**

Comment: One the suggestion of @SLaks, I have checked HTML Utility Pack, can anyone suggest a simple solution without using 3rd party libraries.

Thank you

Comment: Check out this SO answer for using Html Agility Pack - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text/2785108#2785108

Comment: Thank you all for the HTML Utility Pack suggestion, I will definitely consider it, but before doing that can anybody suggest any other way to do this.

Coming to the Webclient class, i have already changed my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which can parse the HTML without IE.
It has an `InnerText` property.

---

To answer your question, you need to wait for the browser to parse the text.

---

By the way, you should use the `WebClient` class instead of `WebRequest`.

Comment: Thank you for the HTML agility pack, i will check that one

Answer (score 1):

Use webclient:

```
public string request_Resource()
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(myuri);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

This will give you the content of the website. Then you can use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the result.

Answer (score -2):

If you need just plain HTML text, then you have already wrote that code.

```
public string request_Resource()
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myurl);
   Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
   return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that i need plain text, i never mentioned plain html. Anyways thank you