# Regular Expression for Extracting Script Tags

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in C# to remove all script tags and anything contained within them.

So far I have come up with the following: `\<([^:]*?:)?script\>[^(\</<([^:]*?:)?script\>)]*?\</script\>`, however this does not work.

I'll break it up and explain my thinking in each section:

```
\<([^:]*?:)?script\>
```

Here I am trying to state that it should get any script element, even if it is prefixed with a namespace, say, `<a:script></a:script>.` I have also added this to the closing tag.

```
[^(\</<([^:]*?:)?script\>)]*?
```

Here I am trying to state that it should allow anything to be contained within the tags except for `</a:script>`, `</script>`, etc.

```
\</script\>
```

Here I am stating that it should have a closing tag.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please provide some of your data and indicate which ones are failing.

Comment: "Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?". Yes. Using regex to parse HTML is your biggest mistake.

Comment: Did you consider using HtmlAgilityPack? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 over and over and over and over and over again

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try the HTMLAgilityPack. I understand the problem: tags within tags would break the thing.

Comment: if you don't care about the formatting, why not just strip the html of new lines/carriage returns and use your regular expression? It works when you treat the string as just 1 line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[You can't parse HTML with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003)

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) instead.

Answer (score 22):

This regular expression does the trick just fine:

```
\<(?:[^:]+:)?script\>.*?\<\/(?:[^:]+:)?script\>
```

### But don't do it please

You will run into a problem by this simple HTML:

```
<script>
var s = "<script></script>";
</script>
```

How are you going to solve this problem? It is smarter to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for such things.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? He asked for a regular expression. I provided one that matches script tags to his requirements. He didn't ask for tools, did he? No. That's our job to suggest a better alternative. **Why the downvote then?** To get your answer higher or what?

Comment: @Robert Possibly because "you can't parse HTML with regex" is one of the main memes on StackOverflow, whereas your answer suggests that parsing HTML with regex is OK

Comment: @Tim Robinson: Actually no. that's why I posted fast and updated my answer few times later. Sometimes people are too hasty about voting. :) Never mind. Maybe my downvoted answer will easier convince @TheBoss to **not parse HTML with regular expressions**. ;)

Comment: It's easy (I think) to overlook (in retrospect) the obvious problem of having elements within other elements. Regex would not be able to handle this.

Comment: Look! This is what happens when you parse HTML with regex! You get downvoted!

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, `<script>  var s = "<script></script>";  </script>` is browsed as `Unterminated string constant` Maybe you meant `<script>  var s = "<script>"</script>";  </script>`

Comment: @sln: What do you mean by unterminated string constant? Yours looks invalid though. Or I'm just being blind. Enlighten me...

Comment: The browser doesn't understand `"</script>"` is quoted.  It *first* finds the end of the script by some [arcane rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) — to a first appoximation looking for the string `</script`.  Only then it parses the content as Javascript and understands quotes.

Comment: Indeed. You will find that the literal character sequence `</script>` may not occur in script sections... your browser does not understand JS, and simply looks for the end tag. In the same way that your browser takes this shortcut is what makes regex fine on this example. Your browser treats the sequence as text, then so can you.