# How to dynamically not render a script tag?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, .net

I want to be able to dynamically (on page load) decide to set it to `Visible=false` so it won't be rendered. I tried `runat=server` but that's only for virtual paths.

Comment: Do you want to remove script tag from source?

Comment: @Adil Sometimes I need it there and sometimes I want it not rendered. That will only be known at runtime.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414829/removing-script-tags-from-html-pages-using-c-sharp

Comment: Consider moving sthis script block to a separate file, and then conditionally register it

Comment: Does `<% if (shouldRenderScriptTag) { %><script ...><% } %>` not work?

Comment: @Andrei That sounds like a good idea. You can make that into an answer.

Comment: @chiccodoro I'll have to test that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @ispiro, well, that is not  aproper answer - we have no idea what your script looks like, and what is the condition you are applying on runtime. This is more an idea, therefore in comments. Good if you like it though

Comment: @chiccodoro Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to conditionally add the script.

```
if (condition)
{    
    String csname2 = "ButtonClickScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
    cstext2.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function DoClick() {");
    cstext2.Append("Form1.Message.value='Text from client script.'} </");
    cstext2.Append("script>");
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname2, cstext2.ToString(), false);
}
```

If you have script that is not small then you can put the script in some **js file** and use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (condition)
{
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude("ScriptKey", "ScriptURLToInclude");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising.

Comment: Why last param is `false`, if you are adding `script` tags?

Comment: As Script tags are present in the string being passed to RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: That's the question - you do not need to do this manually if ASP.NET provides this for you.

Comment: I copied the code from MSDN (include link in my answer) and did not change, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: (I fixed the second link.)

Answer (score 3):

In the ASP.NET markup language you can steer the rendering of any arbitrary contents. That is rendering a script tag only under certain conditions should be as simple as:

```
<% if (shouldRenderScriptTag) { %>
    <script src="..." />
<% } %>
```

Comment: +1. I still can't decide which answer to accept. You answered the actual question, but Adil answered the underlying question. You both deserve the credit. Oh, well, at some point I'll have to decide :) And thanks again.

Comment: @ispiro - the literal answer is so straight-forward that I think it will be of marginal use to the community. If Adil's answer helps you design the code a bit better I'd go for his.