# Prevent XSS in C# Winform WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, xss, owasp

I'm using a C# WebBrowser in my application. This WebBrowser receives an Html input as a string, like this fairly simple portion of code :

```
string HtmlToDisplay = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(RawDataB64));
webBrowser1.DocumentText = HtmlToDisplay;
```

As the WebBrowser component will execute any script included into the Html, I need to prevent XSS attack by "cleaning" the Html string to display.

I first thought of removing the script tag as in this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414886/969881

Or even use HtmlAgilityPack as in that link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414865/969881

But my coworker says that it's not efficient enough, and that I have to use OWASP ESAPI to prevent such an attack.

1/ Is he right ?

2/ If so, is there a means to use OWASP ESAPI as a raw string cleaner of data to display into the webBrowser component ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: So you want selective filtering? i.e all html except script is allowed? - if not, what are the rules?

Comment: I just need to display pure Html and avoid any script, that's the general idea, all CSS and all script tags have to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `script` tag doesn't fully eliminate the usage of JavaScript on a webpage. There are some obvious workarounds to this method.
For example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';" />
```

As for OWASP ESAPI, it's open sourced which means that advanced users who wish to breach your security system(s) can browse the code of the API and potentially find a workaround for it.
For this reason, you should consider purchasing some other kind of security system as well as encoding the string to disable HTML tags from functioning when written to the webpage.
As far as security goes, I would definitely not rely on simply replacing all instances of `<script>` with a blank string. This is definitely not efficient as shown in the example workaround above. Encoding the string is a fairly decent way to prevent most workarounds, although advanced users can find ways.
Therefore to answer your questions:
(1) Yes, he's right that there are more efficient ways than encoding a string
(2) I wouldn't personally recommend using an open sourced string cleaner because users can browse through the code and potentially find a way of breaching the security mechanisms.

Comment: Is that a blanket dismissal of all open source security related software?

Comment: I don't mean that it's safer in terms of the way it's programmed. I simply mean that if the source code can be browsed, then people who wish to breach your site can see how the string encoder functions and can find ways to allow harmful code into the site. If the source is server-side and can't be viewed online, then it's much safer in that sense.

Comment: There's no doubt that open sourced software (like everything) has it's pros and it's cons. When it comes to security, I like to be extremely careful to avoid any potential issues. I'm not at all against open sourced software but for the purposes of security, in my opinion, it's better to go for something which users cannot see how it works.

Comment: Is the Open-Sourced HtmlSanitizer a right way to prevent XSS, as it is open sourced ? Link : https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Comment: Considering that it's configurable in terms of what is denied (attributes as well as tags), it's unknown to the potential threat as to what you've denied access to. For this reason, although it's open sourced, you're able to manipulate it so I'd consider that safe as long as you ensure that you configure all harmful attributes which are to do with JavaScript (such as onhover, onclick, onblur etc).