# Html Encoding/Decoding & Html.Raw

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, summernote

I hear that using HTML.Raw in Razor views is not recommended, and if so I have a problem.

I am using Entity Framework for interacting with my SQL DB. Also I am using SummerNote as an editor for the front end.

Now my view code is in @{ } block, which I believe does some encoding/decoding.

The scenario is that the user inputs some text in the SummerNote editor and applies some formatting (e.g making a word bold) and clicks saves. This will generate an HTML string and passes it to my controller:

```html
<p>Test <b>string </b>with formatting.</p>
```

In the controller, I use HTML encode to encode:

```
customerData.Description = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(summerNoteFieldData);
```

And then send it to DB. It looks like the following in DB:

```
&lt;p&gt;Test &lt;b&gt;string &lt;/b&gt;with formatting.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Then in the view when presenting it, I do:

```
<div class="summernote">@Html.Raw(@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model))</div>
```

So if I remove the Html.Raw, then I will see the above HTML string rather than formatted one.

Is this the safe and right way to go about this? Can it be improved?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no real point in using `HtmlEncode` and `HtmlDecode` in that case

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for the reply. I think so too and I removed them. Now if I just print using `@Model`, then it will print the HTML. In order to print the formatted string I have to wrap it in `@Html.Raw`. I don't know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: But what is your problem? Using `@Html.Raw()` is correct for this.

Comment: Oh is it? that is what I am trying to figure out. So using Html.Raw is not going to pose any security threats?

Comment: Well it will if the user has entered malicious tags (e.g. `<script>`, but you need to take care of that in the POST method and remove them (or return the view with an error if they attempt it). Best to use a library such as [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) to validate it

Comment: Refer [Store and display HTML string while avoiding JS, in ASP.Net Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503360/store-and-display-html-string-while-avoiding-js-in-asp-net-core-2/50508766#50508766) for an example

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. I think that is the answer. I think I should be concerned  about the <script> tag and remove it as early as possible. If you post it as a solution I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should HTML encode as you print in your view (using `@Model`).

Do not encode or decode anywhere else; do not store encoded content in your database.

Comment: thank you for your reply. After removing the Html.Encode in the controller, the string in DB looks like:


`<p>Test <b>string </b>with formatting.</p>`


And I modified the view to just do encode:


`<div class="summernote">@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@Model)</div>`


But then when I refresh the page, I see the following which is not the formatted string:
 

`&lt;p&gt;Test &lt;b&gt;string &lt;/b&gt;with formatting.&lt;/p&gt;`

Comment: `@...` automatically encodes.  You should not call any encoding method.

Comment: So to clarify what should appear in DB? Should I see `<p>Test <b>string </b>with formatting.</p>` ?

Comment: Yes @b3hdad - that is what you should store.

Comment: Thanks, so that direction I am doing the right thing. Now when presenting if I don't do @Html.Raw, then I see the HTML instead of a formatted string. My concern only now is, if Html.Raw poses security threat?

Comment: @b3hdad Not if you filter out all unacceptable tags before you store it.

Comment: I see, I am assuming its only really <script> tag that is dangerous.

Comment: @b3hdad: No; any tag can have dangerous attributes.  You need a whitelist-based filter.  For example, https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Comment: @SLaks thank you so much. I just started using the sanitizer and will run some tests. Also looks like the SummerNote(which is the editor I am trying to secure) has two modes. Code view and Text View. I have disabled the code view and the text view, seems to at least encode the script tags which is good. Cheers.