# making a description text !

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have in my database the News Table which consist of => Id, Title, txt .
I need to be able to get a description text from the whole text which exist in txt Field , but without any codes like <...> , just a pure text !! how can I do this !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string Strip(string source)
{
    char[] array = new char[source.Length];
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    bool inside = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        char let = source[i];
        if (let == '<')
        {
            inside = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (let == '>')
        {
            inside = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (!inside)
        {
            array[arrayIndex] = let;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    }
    string text =  new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net):

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

To extract all the text nodes in the HTML.

This question explains how you would do that:

[C#: HtmlAgilityPack extract inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text)

Answer (score 0):

Can you so something like:

(Get the record first then add a property to return some of the text)

```
return Text.Length >= 100 ? Text.SubString(0,100) : Text;
```

Comment: This gives me the first 100 char , which could be contains a codes .

Comment: Ah in that case, James reply is more relevant