# Can I use HTML Agility Pack in Windows Forms Applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

This is my first time doing my work with HAP, but I find a problem with `HtmlDocument` class, I can't use it, because intellisense tells me that it is ambiguous reference, this is the picture : 
[image]

I have imported the library needed it this code which are `using HTML_Agility;
using HtmlAgilityPack;` and I also add reference to its DLL file but it can't help me so much. Do you know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: did you try `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the ambiguous reference write like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan P for this. now, do you how to get some html content such as text because I want to extract it and show the on my text box?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text

Answer (score 3):

There's also exists a `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` class.

Try explicitly qualifying your classname instead of using a `using` statement, or rename the class with a `using` statement such as `using HAPDocument = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;` (and then use `HAPDocument` instead of `HtmlDocument` in your source code).