# HtmlAgilityPack parse text blocks

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am making a small web analysis tool and need to somehow extract all the text blocks on a given url that contain more than X amount of words.

The method i currently use is this:

```
        public string getAllText(string _html)
    {
        string _allText = "";
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(_html);


            var root = document.DocumentNode;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var node in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
            {
                if (!node.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    string text = node.InnerText;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                        sb.AppendLine(text.Trim());
                }
            }

            _allText = sb.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        _allText = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_allText);

        return _allText;
    }
```

The problem here is that i get all text returned, even if its a meny text, a footer text with 3 words, etc.

I want to analyse the actual content on a page, so my idea is to somehow only parse the text that could be content (ie text blocks with more than X words)

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: the html will be different, some pages might wrap text in p, some in div, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first approach can be a simple word count analisys on each `node.InnerText` value using [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) function:

```
string[] words;
words = text.Split((string[]) null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and append only text where `words.Length` is larger than 3.

Also see [this question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text) for some more tricks in raw text gathering.