# Extracting content from Webpage

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to use `HTMLagilitypack` to extract all the content from the webpage.

```
foreach (HtmlTextNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
{
    sb.AppendLine(node.Text);
}
```

When i try to parse google.com using above code i get lots of javascript. All i want is to extract the content in the webpage like in `h` or `p` tags. Like taking the question,answer,comments on this page and removing everything else.

I am really new to XPath and don't exactly know where to move forward. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok so the problem i was having that innerText of `script` and `style` was also being returned. So for that removal of script and style was necessary all credit goes to this guy [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2785108/1762761)

Comment: I am not familiar with HTMLagilitypack but is sounds strange to me to get a **Text** from a **text()** node. You could try **SelectNodes("//*[text()]")** to get all the node with has a text node.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for the non-wanted tags by name and remove them from your document.

```
        doc = page.Load("http://www.google.com");
        doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style").ToList().ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Comment: That's the thing i don't want to select only h1 tags. Rather i want to select text from the whole page. I don't think i would be able to cover every conceivable combination of tags for text text extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this XPath expression:

```
//body//*[local-name() != 'script']/text()
```

It takes only the elements inside the `body` and skips the `script` elements